# Websockets onMessage function: What happens if the code block within onMessage takes longer to run than interval between two messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, websocket

As a websocket client, we have access to an onMessage function that fires everytime the client receives a message from the server. I am trying to understand what happens if the code block called on the onMessage event takes longer to run the interval between the next message being received.

For example, I tested out the code below:

```
client.onMessage = (event) => {
    console.log('Message Received')
    setTimeout(() => console.log('Delay of 10 seconds'), 10000)
}
```

The output I got was quite strange:

```
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Delay of 10 seconds
Message Received
Delay of 10 seconds
Delay of 10 seconds
Delay of 10 seconds
Message Received
Delay of 10 seconds
Delay of 10 seconds
Message Received
Delay of 10 seconds
Delay of 10 seconds
Delay of 10 seconds
Message Received
Delay of 10 seconds
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Message Received
Delay of 10 seconds
Message Received
```

Anyone has any idea what is going on here?

On a related note, what happens if the function called within the block is an async function like below?

```
client.onMessage = async(event) => {
    console.log('Message Received')
    await setTimeout(() => console.log('Delay of 10 seconds'), 10000)
}
```

Would this just keep executing and adding console.log's to the end of the async queue until memory was full and it gave a buffer error?

Thanks for the insights! :)

Comment: Looks like you received a lot of messages in the first 10 seconds, before the first log happened. Doesn't seem strange

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ah so seems like all those setTimeouts are getting executed later on. How does this happen though since I thought Node was single threaded unless using async functions?

Comment: `setTimeout` does not block, it just queues a message that runs once the timeout expires. Yes, it's single-threaded. If it's busy when the timeout expires (eg `while (true);`), the timeout will wait until that other message has finished before running the next task

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually just checked, it is printing way more than 1 'Delay of 10 seconds' message every 10 seconds so something is off here. EDIT: Ah, nvm figured it out. It is because there are multiple triggers to onMessage every 10 seconds.

Comment: No, that's perfectly understandable - again, `setTimeout` does not block (and `await`ing a `setTimeout` doesn't make sense anyway, since `setTimeout` returns a number, not a Promise)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see, thanks for the clarification. I guess a better question would be that what happens if setTimeout was replaced with blocking code in that case? How would that case be handled?

Comment: Then you *would* be seeing every ``Message Received`` followed by exactly one `Delay of 10 seconds` after 10 seconds (repeating). But such blocking code is rare, and usually indicates a problem with the code

Comment: @CertainPerformance So does that mean that I would miss all the remaining incoming messages during that 10 second delay?

Comment: No, they'd just take a long time to handle. Eg, 3 messages in the first second would mean the 3rd message would be handled at the 30-second mark. But you should almost never see this situation in real code

Comment: @CertainPerformance Got it, thanks a lot for helping me understand :D If a situation like this did arrive, it would eventually result in a BufferOverflow error I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't block. It looks like you're just receiving many messages in the first 10 seconds. Lots of `onMessage` callbacks run immediately, and lots of *future* `setTimeout` callbacks get queued, but the first `setTimeout` callback only starts running after 10 seconds.

> On a related note, what happens if the function called within the block is an async function like below?

Nothing - `async` functions don't block either. `await`ing a `setTimeout` doesn't do anything, because `setTimeout` returns a number, not a Promise.

Even if `setTimeout` returned a Promise, Promises still don't block, so the situation would be the same.

> Would this just keep executing and adding console.log's to the end of the async queue until memory was full and it gave a buffer error?

This would only be a risk if you had actual *blocking* code, eg:

```
client.onMessage = (event) => {
    const now = Date.now();
    console.log('Message Received')
    while (Date.now() - now < 10000);
    console.log('Delay of 10 seconds');
}
```

Here, eventually (might take a *long* time), there would be too many events for the machine's memory to handle, and the script would fail. But such expensive blocking code is rare and often an indication of a problem in the logic, so it's not something to worry about in nearly any sane situation.